# CDK docker asset in CI snapshot test fails for asset fingerprinting (digest)

Tags: docker, jestjs, github-actions, aws-cdk, snapshot

I am running into an issue with CDK testing on github actions

Got a template snapshot test of my cdk stack that passes locally and fails on github actions because of a docker image asset hash diff between what is generated locally and what is generated in CI environment. Checked github workspace directory for the docker build context and all the files are the same - so It's confusing why the generated hash is different ?

Comment: Think I got the same issue, but with Bamboo.

Comment: same on bibucket, I cannot pintpoint the reason though :/

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74769040/12423765

Upd: sorry, re-read your question, feels like that answer won't help here.